# MongoDB Aggregate Query Not Filtering Correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've looked around and I see a lot of similar questions, but I don't quite understand why my code isn't working. I'm fairly new to MongoDB, so I may be using something incorrectly. I'm basically just trying to select a random document but filter out the ones that are passed through an array. In the request body, we have this posting to the server:

```
{
    "chosen_lists": ["62718d522a2b7790b4052331"]
}
```

And I have my code as such to try and filter and return any one random document that does not have that id, like so:

```
const chosenLists = req.body.chosen_lists; 

list = await List.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: { '$nin': chosenLists } }},
  { $sample: { size: 1 } }
], (err, docs) => docs);
```

Unfortunately the server returns just one randomly selected document and not filtering it out. I've also added quotes around `_id` but that did not seem to work either. Thank you ahead of time for your help!

Edit: I'm current passing the ids for chose_lists as strings, and not ObjectIds. I just tried grabbing the first and converting it into an ObjectId and that did not work either:

```
list = await List.aggregate([
  { $match: {  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.chosen_lists[0]) } },
  { $sample: { size: 1 } }
], (err, docs) => docs);
```

Comment: Is `"_id"` a string or an ObjectId?

Comment: It's a string currently.

Comment: So, using your aggregation pipeline, the document with `"_id": "62718d522a2b7790b4052331"` is returned sometimes?  Whether [`"_id"` is a string or an ObjectId](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X6kGCvnhftt "Link to mongoplayground.net example -->") is important.

Comment: Yep, it still returns a document without an issue - it just doesn't return the one I'm not wanting to return. So, passing that `_id` as a string will randomly return one document whether or not it's included in the filter - it just ignores it. I just tried converting it into an ObjectId and that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you want `"$nin"` or `"$in"` in the `"$match"`?

Comment: "$nin", but it looks like I needed to parse the returned project's _id as a string - it's working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `_id` Property is an `ObjectId` you should parse that to String as a following:

```
const List = await List.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          _id: {
            $toString: "$_id"
          }
        }
      },
      { $match: { _id: { '$nin': chosenLists } }},
      { $sample: { size: 1 } }
    ]);
```

Note: The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array as default mongo use it as `ObjectId`.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the primary key associated with the document and it's definitely unique. I currently am already using the id as a string, but tried as an ObjectId as well, which returned the same result.

Comment: I just implemented that parse and I think it's working! Going to double check really quick